# wifi doesn't work after installing ubuntu

Tags: wireless, laptop

i have installed linux alongside windows 10 on my laptop. After that i entered the driver search in linux and found the wifi driver - and the wifi worked correctly. I had to remove windows and reinstall linux, and now the wifi doesn't work `[no drivers avavible]`.

More over - i can't even install packs in the terminal. When i write `sudo apt-get install package name` i get a message in which said that this package does not exist and I don't know what to do.
Thanks.

Edit:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and using `wl` kernel driver

Connect to the internet

Open a Terminal and install the bcmwl-kernel-source package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Load driver

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Other way to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` from [here](https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu)

add repo and install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/bcmwl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

compile

```
sudo apt-get install git-buildpackage
mkdir bcmwl-ubuntu
cd bcmwl-ubuntu
git clone https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu.git bcmwl-ubuntu-master
cd bcmwl-ubuntu-master
gbp buildpackage -b -uc -us
ls ../*.deb
../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-1longsleep0_amd64.deb
 sudo dpkg -i ../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-1longsleep0_amd64.deb
```